# Instruments refuse to run

Tags: xcode, instruments

I am having problem running my Instruments on my iPhone app, below is the message I got.  Any idea what's causing this and what I can do?

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090831-qxf5t5g4igc4g1xp4gm529mxgk.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090831-qxf5t5g4igc4g1xp4gm529mxgk.png)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your Xcode/Mac OS X installation is not compromised in some fashion, one of the few reasons that might happen is if you failed to authenticate for debugging purposes.

Comment: What should I do to fix this?

Comment: File a bug, include any useful output found in the console, and consider a reinstall.  If you installed Snow Leopard, did you also install Xcode from the DVD, too?